# jQuery validation - validate specific rules/methods on keypress for specific fields

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Using jquery validation:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I am also validating each field on blur:

```
//validate each element on blur
    $('input, select, radio, checkbox').blur(function(){
        $("#createAccount").validate().element(this);
    });
```

I added an additional method for passwords - alpha, numeric, no spaces/dashes:

```
//Additional validation methods:
jQuery.validator.addMethod("passwordCheck", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, "Invalid characters");
```

A couple of issues:

I would like to validate the password field on blur for everything but the passwordCheck method. So other methods, such as required, should validate on blur - but if an invalid character is entered, then I want the validator to trigger that method then.

Additionally, when adding methods, is there a way to get the error message into the messages portion of the validation call (just to keep them all in one place)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second question, but here's what we do to collect error messages: function postMessage(jq, msg) {jq.before('<span class="validationError">' + msg + '</span>');}  where jq is a jQuery of a status area on the page.  You can call postMessage() multiple times.  To clean up, jq.find('.validationError').remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to accomplish this:

For an input that needed to be ignored until it had a value I added a class to the input - "ignore"

```
$('.ignore').blur(function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="") {
         $(this).parent().removeClass("inputSuccess");
        }
    });
```

In the function, if an input has the class ignore and no value has been entered, then I remove the valid class I set in the validate call. When a value is entered, the normal validations will trigger on those items.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 supports the `required` attribute.
So you can check it by something like:

```
<input type="password" name="password" required />
```

and

```
return !$(element).hasAttr("required");
```

This forces you to enter the field before submitting the form, though.
In addition, you could create a custom attribute, but I don't know if that's a good solution.

http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Techniques/HTML5/Using_the_required_attribute_to_indicate_a_required_input_field